# Variable and exception handling in Python - do they mix?

Tags: python, exception, beautifulsoup

I am working on a project requiring me to scan through a large number of HTML-files (8000+). Some of these files are broken but this is an inevitable consequence of the source of the files, and cannot be fixed.

I have chosen to use BeautifulSoup4 to find and extract the data. The code for this is the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = open('data\file.html', encoding='utf-8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

tag = soup.find('strong', text="Heading:")

split_tag = str(tag.next_sibling.next_element.next_element).split(", ")
```

What it does is that it opens a file, searches for a strong-tag containing the text "Heading:". Then it splits the contents of this tag at the commas.

However, if the source file is broken it does not have a strong-tag containing the text "Heading:". Therefore, an AttributeError is raised at split_tag due to the fact that it returns "None" and therefore does not have any next_sibling.

I tried to fix this by using the following method:

```
try:
    split_tag = str(tag.next_sibling.next_element.next_element).split(", ")
except AttributeError:
    pass
else:
    split_tag = str(tag.next_sibling.next_element.next_element).split(", ")
```

This did not work. I also tried expressing this as a function but no luck.

So I turn to you. What I want to do is to split the contents at the commas if there are any contents. If not, the script should just pass.

I am very grateful for any assistance!

Comment: Without seeing the actual error that you got, I can't say much. Post the error that you get. `This did not work` doesn't help anyone figure out what's wrong with your code

Comment: Your `else` block serves no purpose, as it is only reached if the `try` block already did exactly the same thing, but your code should "work" as it is.

Comment: Are you getting an unbound local error later on? You're not assigning split_tag in your exception handler clause.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget:
The error which displays is the following:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "[Path to python file]", line 8, in <module>
    split_tag = str(tag.next_sibling.next_element.next_element).split(", ")
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next_sibling'`

@modelnine:
I'm not quite sure what that means.

Comment: @luke14free: I have now tried you suggestion. The problem is that the variable split_tag is not defined and therefore it raises the following exception: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[path]", line 13, in <module>
    print(split_tag)
NameError: name 'split_tag' is not defined`

Comment: I agree, you were catching the error, and then reitroducing it in the else, which is not caught.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would rewrite your exception handler.  If there is no such heading, then we should expect to get a zero-length list of tags.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = open('data\file.html', encoding='utf-8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

tag = soup.find('strong', text="Heading:")

try:
    split_tag = str(tag.next_sibling.next_element.next_element).split(", ")
except AttributeError:
    split_tag = []  # zero-length list of tags
```

But in this case a simple `if` statement should work well, because `soup.find()` is returning `None` when nothing is found.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = open('data\file.html', encoding='utf-8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

tag = soup.find('strong', text="Heading:")

if tag is None:
    split_tag = []
else:
    split_tag = str(tag.next_sibling.next_element.next_element).split(", ")
```

When checking for `None`, it is best to use the `is` test for object identity, as I showed above.